# How to place the video player directly on top of the current screen on the mobile web?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mobile-website, video-player

(First of all, I am sorry for my poor English.)

I'm working on a mobile web project right now. I want to show you the detail info of the video, and if you press the 'Watch Video' button at the bottom of the screen, I want the video to be played with the default player. Instead, I want it to play directly from the existing page, (without developing a separate page) but I'm wondering what to do.

I want to implement it like the NTC (Nike Training) app.

When I press the "Start Exercise" button on the NTC app, the video player appears with the transition as if a layer is placed on an existing page, is it possible to implement this on the web, not on the app?

The default player appears as shown in the picture below, (I'm using an iPhone)
It didn't seem to be a separate page.

[NTC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8plD.jpg)

---

1. Can the above method be implemented on the web, not on the mobile app?
2. How do I float the default player directly from an existing page like the NTC app?

I tried opening it in a new tab first.

```html
<a
  href="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"
  target="_blank"
  rel="noopener noreferrer"
>
  Watch Video
</a>
```

But it didn't seem like the way I wanted it to be.

And I tried googling with several keywords, but I couldn't find this case.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Do you want to display it in the full screen or in a modal?